# How to change CSS from blueprint CSS framework in cassius?

Tags: css, haskell, blueprint-css, yesod

I use blueprint CSS framework. the blueprint files are placed in static/ and are linked to in default-layout.hamlet like this:

```
<link rel=stylesheet media=screen href=@{StaticR blueprint_screen_css}>
<link rel=stylesheet media=print href=@{StaticR blueprint_print_css}>
```

In blueprint CSS, body background is defined as white. In default-layout.cassius I want to change background in another color... but it seems impossible...

Is this because the order of css/cassius/lucius-interpretation?
And if so, can it be turned around?

Comment: Where is the default-layout stylesheet included in the page head?

Comment: Can you post your entire <head> tag contents? Most likely, you need to move the pageHead call to after your <link> tags.

Answer (score 1):

The head-part was

```
<head
    <title>Yesod Tutorial Micropost | #{pageTitle pc}
    ^{pageHead pc}
<link rel=stylesheet media=screen href=@{StaticR blueprint_screen_css}>
<link rel=stylesheet media=print href=@{StaticR blueprint_print_css}>
```

and by changing the order into

```
<head
    <title>Yesod Tutorial Micropost | #{pageTitle pc}
<link rel=stylesheet media=screen href=@{StaticR blueprint_screen_css}>
<link rel=stylesheet media=print href=@{StaticR blueprint_print_css}>
    ^{pageHead pc}
```

the problem is solved.